# Unassign an assigned process from a job object

Tags: c++, windows

I m using assignprocesstojobobject to kill all child process when the parent dies.
However under sone circumstances I wish not to kill some of them.
So I thought I could just unassign a proceo however the documentation mentions nothing like that...
Any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: The docs say "If the process is already associated with a job, the job specified by hJob must be empty or it must be in the hierarchy of nested jobs to which the process already belongs" - can you test calling it with an empty job handle and see if that does what you need?  The docs are unclear on what it does in that case, so better to just try.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I thought about this as well... Call me lazy. I ll try it out and revert with the results

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is quite clear, see [Job Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx):

> After a process is associated with a job, the association cannot be broken.